# Is it possible to animate like this image with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, animation

just a simple question. I want to make a simple animation using only CSS/Html5 with final result similar to this image but with fadeout effects.

I already can generate the text in random positions and fadeout, but... what about the colors? It is possible to make this color transitions and with transparency? I mean, can the text have this effect?

As a newbie, i appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want text with transparency, you just have to use rgba colors like this:

```
color: rgba(123,213,231,0.5);
```

Where the last numner "0.5" is the transparency of the color.
For an animation effect on color change [use transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: Thank you. I guess using alpha is the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize text color with javascript:

```
function randomColor() {
  return 'rgba('+rgb()+','+rgb()+','+rgb()+','+alpha()+')';
}
function rgb() {
  var min = 0,
  max = 255,
  rcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  return rcolor;
}
function alpha() {
  var min = 0.2,
  max = 0.9,
  randalpha = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  return randalpha.toFixed(1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ullvieib/cbuy2gka/

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i would like to apply some effect not only set a random color (Although your solution is great!) . I mean,  what about one letter have a multicolor effect like the image?